# Disabling prefix key binding

Tags: shell, emacs, key-bindings, emacs23

In shell mode on emacs, the current key binding for quitting the shell mode (`'comint-interrupt-subjob`) is `"\C-c \C-c"`, and I want to change it to `"\C-c"` as in ordinary linux shell. I tried

```
(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook '(lambda ()
  (local-set-key "\C-c" 'comint-interrupt-subjob)
))
```

But it did not work. Probably I need to disable the prefix assigned to `"\C-c"`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
(eval-after-load "shell"
  '(define-key shell-mode-map (kbd "C-c") 'comint-interrupt-subjob))
```

In general, when you define keys you should define them in particular keymaps, as opposed to just hoping the `local-set-key` does what you want.

Note: I prefer using `kbd` for describing keys, your `"\C-c"` would work just fine.

Comment: Thank you again. Good to know about `kbd`. I tried it but after "\C-", it still seems to be waiting for continuation, meaning that suffix is still active. Any ideas why this is so?

Answer (score 2):

```
(define-key (current-local-map) "^C" 'comint-interrupt-subjob)
```

This will do the work without the error checking of local-set-key

Comment: I tried this, but it returns `Wrong type argument: keymapp, nil`.

Comment: @sawa: What version of emacs are you using?  It works fine for me in Emacs 23.3.1  Please note that ^C is a literal ^C (meaning type ^Q^C) or you can use the (kbd "C-c") thing that Trey described.

Comment: I was trying it on 23.2, and I upgraded to 23.3. This time, Trey's solution worked but yours didn't. Thanks anyway for help. It is often said that emacs has few bugs, I feel the opposite.

Comment: It turned out that a library called 'tabbarl.el' was interfering. The problem is solved.