# Disabling minor mode key bindings

Tags: emacs, key-bindings, emacs23

I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474502/disabling-prefix-key-binding), and got good responses, but the problem turned out to be different from what I had thought.

I am trying to assign a certain function to the key `"C-c"` in shell mode, but it seems that a minor mode called [`tabbar-mode`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/tabbar.el) has a prefix-key assigned to `"C-c"`, which overrides my setting for shell mode. How can I disable tabbar mode key assignments?

I put these after `(require 'tabbar)`, but they did not work:

```
(defvar tabbar-mode-map nil)
(defvar tabbar-prefix-key nil)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(defvar)` only initialises a variable if it has no value. See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>`defvar`<kbd>RET</kbd> for details.

Use `(setq)` to change the value of an existing variable.

To prevent the mode's keymap from being used when looking up key-bindings, you can delete it from the `minor-mode-map-alist` variable:

```
(assq-delete-all 'tabbar-mode minor-mode-map-alist)
```